# Google app consent screen : Image always invalid

Tags: image, web, oauth-2.0

I am in the process of integrating Google's authentification API for my website.
I have create a google API app, and everything is working fine except **setting up the logo for the consent screen at https://console.developers.google.com**

I have tried different images with different sizes and format. The answer is always : "INVALID IMAGE"

**For exemple, does anyone know why the following image is considered "INVALID"?**

http://www.youni.education/images/youni-logo-g.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution : 
I ended up selecting the image of the twitter account of the website and it works.

I don't understand why the image I submitted where considered invalid. But I suspect submitting an image from a well-know host (such as twitter) did the trick.

IMO there is definetly something wrong on https://console.developers.google.com part. They could at least let the user know why an image is invalid.